# AttributeError: module 'pandas.api' has no attribute 'indexers'

Tags: python, pandas

I receive the following error: `AttributeError: module 'pandas.api' has no attribute 'indexers'`
when executing this code, which is directly copied from the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'B': [0, 1, 2, np.nan, 4]})

indexer = pd.api.indexers.FixedForwardWindowIndexer(window_size=2)
df.rolling(window=indexer, min_periods=1).sum()
```

There is no remark in the documentation that this is a new feature or anything, I also tried to search for: `FixedForwardWindowIndexer` inside the pandas files but without sucess.

1. Is there a way to fix this error so that I can use this class?
2. Or alternatively are there any alternatives to solve the rolling window looking into the future?

---

*Python 3.6.9 :: Anaconda, Inc.*

*pd.**version** '0.25.1*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upgrade pandas, because need at least pandas 1.1.0 - [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v1.1.0.html?highlight=fixedforwardwindowindexer):

> Added a pandas.api.indexers.FixedForwardWindowIndexer() class to support forward-looking windows during rolling operations.

Comment: Ah I see, thank you very much. I was confused because I notices that on some entries in the documentation there is mentioned that it is a new feature, here it seems its missing.

Comment: This is really useful and great info, thanks for sharing sir cheers.